# Dynamicly created repeater and ItemCommand event problem

Tags: asp.net

A strange problem.
On my page i have a placeholder where I create a repeater on run time.
In ItemTemplate i have a button that invokes repeater_ItemCommand event.

I put a breakpoint on first line of repeater_ItemCommand event, when the button is triggered the event is invoked as planned, **but** after  RebindRepeaters() is finished, when i click on the button again repeater_ItemCommand event **is not invoked**! 
Only if i click on the button one again it invokes, in other scenarios(this is simple version of my page, in original page i have updatepanel that complex everything) it never invokes!

My aspx code:

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="talk">          
          <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </div>
```

My Code-behind:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RebindRepeaters();
}

void RebindRepeaters()
{
    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Clear();     
    CreateRepeater(PlaceHolder1);
} 

void CreateRepeater(Control container)
{
    Repeater repeater1 = new Repeater();       

    repeater1.ItemCommand += new RepeaterCommandEventHandler(repeater_ItemCommand);
    repeater1.ItemTemplate = Page.LoadTemplate("CommentsTemplate.ascx");
    container.Controls.Add(repeater1);

    repeater1.DataSource = Comment.GetCommentsP(8, 0);
    repeater1.DataBind();
}

void repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {                          
        case "Edit":               
            RebindRepeaters();
            break;
    }
}
```

The CommentsTemplate.ascx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="CommentsTemplate.ascx.cs" Inherits="CommentsTemplate" %>

 <ul>
    <li>
      <div class="show">

         <div class="c">                  
             <asp:LinkButton ID="lbtnTitle" runat="server"  Text='<%#Eval("EncodedTitle")%>' 
                 CausesValidation="false"  CommandName="VoteUp" OnClientClick="viewHide(this);return false;"   CommandArgument='<%#Eval("ID")%>'></asp:LinkButton>                              
             <p class="d"><%#Eval("AddedBy")%>,<%#Eval("AddedDate")%></p>
             <div class="CommentBody"><%# Eval("EncodedBody") %>
             </div>
         </div>
             <div class="userpanel">


               <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panAdmin" Visible='<%# UserCanEdit %>' style="float:left;">
                 <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnSelect" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                     CausesValidation="false" AlternateText="Edit comment" ImageUrl="~/Images/Edit.gif"  />                
                 <asp:ImageButton runat="server" ID="btnDelete" CommandName="Delete" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>'
                   CausesValidation="false" AlternateText="Delete comment" ImageUrl="~/Images/Delete.gif"
                   OnClientClick="if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this comment?') == false) return false;" />
               </asp:Panel>  

             </div>                                                        
      </div>                
            </li>
 </ul>
```

If you need more info just ask.

Comment: What does CommentsTemplate.ascx look like? can you show us the source?

Comment: sure, i didn't think it's relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try overidding createChildcontrols and add the RebindRepeaters call there instead of in Page_Init? And make sure to give your repeater an explicit ID:

```
Repeater repeater1 = new Repeater(); 
repeater1.ID = "repeater1";
```

Without an id the asp.net event handling won't know where the event was called from.

Comment: There is a problem with giving specific id, because on my full page I create nested repeaters (n-level).
And why do I need createChildcontrols ? what's wrong with page_init?

Comment: CreateChildControls gets called at the correct moment in the asp.net page's lifecycle. And if your create nested repeaters you could use a method that uses a page level repeaterlevel Property to keep track on which level you are, so you can increment that when added a nested repeater and use the value in the ID?

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic controls have to be re-added on every postback in order for their events to fire.  A new control tree is being created on the postback and the dynamic control is no longer in it, therefore ASP.NET can't evaluate the change in order to fire the event.

EDIT:  I was able to fire the event each click by removing RebindRepeaters().  You were binding it twice, once here and once in (Page_Init):

```
void repeater_ItemCommand(object sender, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.CommandName)
    {                          
        case "Edit":               
            //RebindRepeaters();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested your source, see EDIT above.